# How to use standalone libraries in Angular mono repo?

Tags: angular, angular-library, monorepo

I am working on new Angular Monorepo Application with multiple single page apps and libraries. There are 6 spa's and 1 header and footer libraries. Header and footer libraries are consumed in all apps.

If I made any change in the header library I need to build all individual apps which is trouble. Is there any way to deploy header and footer libraries as standalone and it can be consumed in all Apps. Or What will be better approach to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.